# Timeout error 110 when trying to import mysql dump on VPS

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, import

I just bought VPS server, its pretty low for now(2ghz cpu, 2gb ram, centos 6 32bit), because it's trial and i think that it might be causing the issue. Anyway, i'm trying to import magento backup, 300mb file. i tried using normal comand and source. I can see in processlist and in phpmyadmin that it's working, but it interrupts after adding 130 from 400 tables and i have this error:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Sp' (110)
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
```

Also checked mysql log file, but nothing in there

/////////////////
Problem solved

Ok, i tried uploading old backup and it works, probably file was corupted when i replaced few tables in notepad++.

Comment: `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'UPTIME';` after the server becomes available... it sounds like the server is crashing because of something in the dump file (possibly a  MySQL version mismatch?)

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin is recommended for large dumps. You can use MySQL command line to import again:

1. Login to your VPS
2. Upload your dump file somewhere in VPS. For example, let's assume you upload your dump at `/var/dump.sql`
3. Login to MySQL - you can do like `$ mysql -uroot -p`. If you press enter, it will ask you password. Please enter password root user (defined when you installed MySQL server). You have to do this in your VPS command line.
4. Select your database, do `$ use <your-db-name>`
5. Run the sql from dump, do `$ source /var/dump.sql`

*the `$` sign from all command examples above just denotes the command prompt (remove it from your own commands).

Comment: No, i mentioned in my question that i try source dbname.sql also i added logs in my first post